Covariant derivative defined by Maurer-Cartan form
Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $H$ be a closed Lie subgroup with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ embedded in $\mathfrak{g}$.
Suppose we have chosen a complementary subspace $\mathfrak{k}$ so that one can write
\begin{equation}
    \mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{h} \oplus  \mathfrak{k}. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) 
\end{equation}
Then, the Maurer-Cartan form denoted by $\Theta$ on $G$ can be splited as
\begin{equation}
    \Theta=w+e \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{equation} where $w$ and $e$ are $\mathfrak{h}$-valued and $\mathfrak{k}$-valued 1-forms on $G$ respectively.
On the other hand, one has the principal $H$-bundle, $\pi:G\longrightarrow G/H$ where $\pi$ is the canonical projection, i.e, $\pi(g)=gH$ and
suppose that we choose a local section, namely a smooth map $L:U \longrightarrow G$ from an open subset $U\subseteq G/H$ of $G/H$ into $G$ satisfying $\pi \circ L = Id_U$.
Moreover, say, we are given another smooth map $\Phi:M \longrightarrow G/H$ where $M$ is just a smooth manifold.
Thus, the composition of these two maps yields the following smooth map,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} \equiv L \circ \Phi : M \longrightarrow G \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)
\end{equation} which makes us able to pull-back $\Theta$ on $M$.
Now, as the $G$ is a matrix Lie group, the pulled-back $\Theta$ at any point on $M$ (under a chart with coordinates $x^\mu$) can be written as
\begin{equation}
    (\mathcal{L}^{-1} \partial_\mu \mathcal{L})dx^\mu=(\mathbf{w}_\mu + \mathbf{e}_\mu)dx^\mu \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)
\end{equation} or in components
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L}^{-1} \partial_\mu \mathcal{L}=\mathbf{w}_\mu + \mathbf{e}_\mu \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (5)
\end{equation} where $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{e}$ are the pull-backs of $w$ and $e$ with the map $\mathcal{L}$ and we just drop the $x$ dependence, i.e, $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}(x)$ for $x\in M$.
Then, one defines the so-called covariant derivative as follows
\begin{equation}
     D_\mu \mathcal{L}\equiv\partial_\mu \mathcal{L}- \mathcal{L} \mathbf{w}_\mu \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (6)
\end{equation} which is indeed equal to $\mathcal{L}\mathbf{e}_\mu$.
In summary, we just multiply the matrix equation $(5)$ with the matrix $\mathcal{L}$ to get the definition of covariant derivative.
Using charts and considering matrices, the construction is crystal clear.
However, I wonder how this covariant derivative can be properly defined without using coordinates in the first place.
I have encountered the covariant derivative defined for principal bundles while looking for a possible answer, but the connection, if it exists at all, is still not clear unfortunately.
Can anyone provide a coordinate-independent definition of the covariant derivative mentioned above?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Could you state what the principal bundle is in your situation?

Sure, let me edit the question to be more clear what it means.
